# How do I reboot my iMac, after I cleared a virus and the computer froze?

Tags: reboot

Ran an virus scan which detected a geneio virus, removed the virus and the computer froze. I only have the Apple icon a spinning wheel. How can I reboot?

Answer (score 2):

You can hold down the power button for 5 seconds to force a power down and then press it again to power it on. The power button, if you're looking at the front of the computer, is located on the back in the lower left hand corner.

[image]